# How can I put several paragraphs in a cell in Rtf 1

Tags: rtf, paragraph

I can use a paragraph in a cell with this code:

```
\trowd\cellx3000\pard\intbl\ltrpar\cf1\f0\fs24 aaaaa \cell\row
```

But using 2 or more paragraphs is a problem for me. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some searches and found this: 
we can not use `\par` in cell part. instead of that ,we can use `\line`